# DataFrames repeat combination

Tags: python, pandas

I have the DataFrame df1 and df2:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['A1','A2']) 
    0
0  A1
1  A2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2016-01-01',periods = 2, freq = '1D'))
           0
0 2016-01-01
1 2016-01-02
```

how am i gonna get this dataframe?

```
    0    1
0  A1  2016-01-01
1  A1  2016-01-02
2  A2  2016-01-01
3  A2  2016-01-02
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use itertools:

```
import itertools as it

pd.DataFrame(list(it.product(df1[0], df2[0])))
    0          1
0  A1 2016-01-01
1  A1 2016-01-02
2  A2 2016-01-01
3  A2 2016-01-02
```

`itertools` returns an generator, so you need to convert it into a list before converting it to a DataFrame

`it.product` makes all combinations between two iterables objects, eg.:

```
["".join(i) for i in it.product("ABC", "ABC")]
['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC']
```

Comment: I just know this product called "Cartesian product", thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `pandas.concat` to expand your dataframes and then merge its.

```
import pandas as pd
# test data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['A1','A2']) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2016-01-01',periods = 2, freq = '1D'))

# expand dataframes to cover all varinats and get the same lengths
df3 = pd.concat([df1]*len(df2), ignore_index=True)
df4 = pd.concat([df2]*len(df2), ignore_index=True)

# final concat to merge dataframes
print (pd.concat([df3,df4],axis=1, ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
    0          1
0  A1 2016-01-01
1  A2 2016-01-02
2  A1 2016-01-01
3  A2 2016-01-02
```